# Shard rebalance issue on addition of new data nodes across the Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

we were running ES cluster version 2.4.0 with 3 master, 3data nodes and one client node. this time shards were evenly distributed to all three data nodes. now to increase the storage and computing power we added the two new data node to the cluster. we were assuming that the moment we new data nodes to cluster ES will rebalance the shard allocation across across the cluster. but it didn't happened. old shards are still allocated to old data nodes and the new shards which are being created in the cluster are being only assigned to new data nodes.

we tried restarting complete ES cluster restart but it didn't helped.

then tried to update the bellow settings in hope that ES will try to rebalance the shards across the cluster but it didn't worked.

`/_cluster/settings`

```
{"persistent":{"indices":{"breaker":{"fielddata":{"limit":"60%"}}}},"transient":{"cluster":{"routing":{"rebalance":{"enable":"all"},"allocation":{"allow_rebalance":"indices_all_active","cluster_concurrent_rebalance":"5","disk":{"watermark":{"low":"50%","high":"300gb"}},"balance":{"shard":"1.0f"}}},"info":{"update":{"interval":"1m"}}}}}
```

any suggestions how we can rebalance the shards allocation evenly across all the data nodes?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `GET /_nodes?pretty` in a gist?

Comment: @AndreiStefan: it got solved. issue was due to version mismatch in cluster.

Comment: Great. Thanks for taking the time to provide feedback about the solution.